# Get started with gazebo

Tags: gazebo, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I just started to play with ROS and gazebo. I've went through the gazebo tutorial and wanted to move to pr2_gazebo tutorial. But now, I'm have problems of installing pr2_gazebo.

First, I checked out the pr2_simulator at (https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_simulator)
Then, I tried
"rosdep install pr2_gazebo",
but got a bunch of error messages (e.g., Failed to find stack for package [joint_trajectory_action]).

Where should I get those dependency packages? I appreciate any pointers to get me started with pr2 simulator.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10086/get-started-with-gazebo/) by [roboren](https://answers.ros.org/users/609/roboren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2011-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up with manually download all missing dependency packages, and it seems working now.

---

Originally posted by [roboren](https://answers.ros.org/users/609/roboren/) with karma: 18 on 2011-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0